# Relative singular homology $H(M,\partial M)$ for a manifold $M$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be an orientable manifold. What can be said about the relative homology $H(M,\partial M)$? Perhaps one can calculate the homology using excision?

Comment: When $M$ is closed, connected and orientable (or non-orientable but with $\Bbb Z/2$ coefficients) then there is a canonical generator $[M,\partial M]\in H_n(M,\partial M)$ in the top dimension $n=\dim M$, called the fundamental class. Under the connecting homomorphism $\partial$ associated to the pair $(M,\partial M)$ it is mapped to the fundamental class of $\partial M$: $$\partial([M,\partial M])=[\partial M]$$ This is well-known material, in case you are unfamiliar with it, you can look it up in the appendix (I believe) of Milnor-Stasheff's classic text *Characteristic Classes*.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat thanks for the information! Is there a more modern treatment of this field that you recommend?

Comment: if you don't know this, it is modern enough for you. It is still the standard reference.

Comment: @Internetsheriffabc123 understood. Thank you.